# Delete from three table in sql or YII

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, yii2

**Please Anyone there**

> Please anyone give me A query to delete from three tables of the
>   following tables

```
DELETE FROM adl_auth_user A JOIN user_details B 
ON A.user_id= B.user_id JOIN adl_user_master C ON A.user_id = C.id where A.user_id = '1920' and B.type_id = 1
```

**its not working**

Table adl_auth_user A

```
id      user_id     type_id     type_value  
66428     1919          1           97
```

table user_details B

```
user_id     first_name      last_nam    
1919        Rins TE       Kola
```

table adl_user C

```
id         email                   password 
1919    email@DOMAIN.COM         SOME PASSWORD
```

> i want delete from these three

```
tables table1. user_id = table2.
> user_id and table1. user_id = table3.id
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ Please show us what you have tried. StackOverflow is not a writing code for others service.

Comment: Sorry sir ..its upto my knowledge ...i will rewritten as possible

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. It's not too hard to find something about it. Just try to get information how you can find a value about 3 tables and how you can delete values in a table. Then you got the knowledge to resolve the problem or come back to us with your idea how you think you could solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I Got the Answer

```
DELETE A,
B,
C FROM adl_auth_user A JOIN user_details B ON A.user_id = B.user_id JOIN adl_user C ON A.user_id = C.id WHERE A.user_id = '1920' AND A.type_id =1
```